# Using WebSockets with AngularJS and $broadcast

Tags: angularjs, websocket, broadcast

I've setup an AngularJS app using websockets and it seems to be working.  Here is a summary of whats going on:

```
var app = angular.module('websocketApp',[]);

app.factory('WebSocket',function($rootScope) {
    var websocket = new WebSocket(websocket_url);
    var items = [];

    websocket.onmessage = function(msg) {
        items.push(JSON.parse(msg.data));
        $rootScope.$broadcast('new_message');    
    }

    return {
        fetchItems: function() {
            return items;
        }
    }
});

app.controller('ItemsCtrl',function($scope,WebSocket) {
    $scope.$on('new_message',function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.items = WebSocket.fetchItems();
        });
    });
});
```

My question is if anyone else has setup an Angular app using websockets and if this implementation is the correct way to go about it or if there is a better solution.  I've read many cons on using $broadcast but this seems to be the correct usage of the $broadcast functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have done it seems fine. An alternative way I do it though is to store an event/callback array, and register the events on it that I want to receive specifically.

For example:

```
angular.module('myapp.services.socket', [])
    .factory('io', ['$rootScope', 'globals', function ($rootScope, globals) {

        var socket;
        var curChannel;
        var eventCache = [];

        function isConnected() {
            return socket && socket.socket.connected;
        }

        function on(eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function () {  
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        }

        function emit(eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {                      
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        return {
            registerEvent: function(eventName, callback) {
                eventCache.push({ name: eventName, cb: callback });
                if(isConnected()){
                    on(eventName, callback);
                }
            },  
            emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {                
                // firstly check that the socket is connected
                if(isConnected()){
                    emit(eventName, data, callback);
                }else{                  
                    // connect to the server and subscribe upon connection
                    socket = io.connect(globals.api + ':80');

                    socket.on('connect', function(){
                        emit(eventName, data, callback);

                        // add the events from the cache
                        for(var i in eventCache){
                            on(eventCache[i].name, eventCache[i].cb);
                        }
                    });
                }               
            }
        };
    }]);
```

This way, you can simply register event callbacks whenever you want, by injecting this service, and running:

`io.registerEvent('some_event', function(){ /* some logic */ });`